# gem install, main requires error message

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm trying to install the metric_fu gem on a new gemset (in rvm), however I get this error:

```
Unable to resolve dependencies: metric_fu requires chronic (~> 0.3.0); churn requires chronic (>= 0.2.3); main requires chronic (~> 0.6.2)
```

I'm trying to debug what's wrong with dependencies, but I don't understand what is the `main` mentioned in the error message which `requires chronic (~> 0.6.2)`. How to solve that?

I have installed the same gem (actually metrical, which is only a wrapper for metric_fu) on my mac with a very similar configuration some months ago and I don't remember any dependency issue at that time.

I've updated rubygem to the latest version (1.8.8) to see if something changes but it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, thanks to ridecar2 hint here is how I'm solved it through bundler:

```
rails new testapp && cd testapp
echo "gem 'metrical'" >> Gemfile
bundle install
cd .. && rm -rf testapp
```

Bundler will take care of dependencies and then I have the `metrical` binary available for my projects.

```
$ gem list | grep metric  
metric_fu (2.1.1)
metrical (0.0.5)
```

For the records: I don't want `metrical` nor `metric_fu` in my original rails project to keep it simple as suggested in [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/252-metrics-metrics-metrics)

Answer (score 2):

You need two versions of chronic installed, 0.3.x and 0.6.x, for that to work. This can't be done afaik, so you're stuck until metric_fu gets an upgrade.

Comment: Ok, that is the issue, but what is the `main` which requires `~> 0.6.2`, rubygems itself? I don't think so also because I've a similar setup which is working with same versions (i.e. metric_fu=0.2.2)

Comment: Main is this: https://github.com/ahoward/main. I don't know what depends on it though.

Comment: You got it, I havent understood that main is the name of a gem, now I'm working on how to solve that dependency issue.